# Excel blurry and bold text in ribbon

Tags: microsoft-excel-2019

I have a new computer (Windows 10 Pro N 64bit) and I installed a clean MS Office & Business 2019 (also 64bit).

There is a strange problem with Excel: some of the text in the ribbon are bold and blurry. See attached image for styles.

[image]

What could be the problem?

Note (what I already did):

- checked that my Windows has all the latest updates
- same for Office
- same for computer hardware (using HP Support Assistant)

Comment: That looks like text scaling. Do other applications exhibit this issue? It's a system-wide setting.

Comment: this is the only app with this problem. Also the problem is exclusive to the HOME/STYLES section of the Excel ribbon

Comment: Might be Non-Standard Screen resolution. Temporarily, try changing the Screen resolution higher or lower and check whether the Problem increases or reduces.

Comment: It wasn't the resolution. I had the "make text bigger" in Disply settings set to 113%. I turned back to 100% and the problem is gone. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the setting to make text bigger (Windows 10, Ease of Access > Display settings).

Turning the setting to 100% eliminates the problem.